# How to find number of values Grouped by MySQL groupby query

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any solution to find number of values Grouped by MySQL groupby query. Following is my Query.
`$groupBy = 'PropertyViewer.ip_address';`
`$this->paginate = array("group"=>array($groupBy),"order"=>array("PropertyViewer.id desc"));`

I need to find how many values grouped in each case.

Comment: if you can show your query here, we can help you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh query mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need is the `COUNT()` aggregate function in your SELECT query:

```
SELECT COUNT( ip_address) as num_values
     FROM PropertyViewer
GROUP BY PropertyViewer.ip_address
ORDER BY PropertyViewer.id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT count(PropertyViewer.ip_address) will show you how many times the IP address shows up if that is what you are looking for.